# why AsyncTask must be subclassed to be used?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Developer document for android says "AsyncTask must be subclassed to be used"! why it should be subclassed? Is their any problem if I use a AsyncTask simply inside a function like as shown below

```
     private void processXMLinBackground(final String Url) {

    new AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Entry>>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Entry> result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Entry> doInBackground(String... params) {
            return NewList;

        }

    }.execute(Url, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the class is `abstract`, and you have to provide an implementation of `doInBackground`

Comment: Then why the above method works correctly? I dint subclassed it

Comment: Yes you did. You just did it anonymously.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instanciate an abstract class by definition, here it is to clear your mind on this point :

> Abstract classes cannot be instantiated; they must be subclassed, and
>   actual implementations must be provided for the abstract methods. Any
>   implementation specified can, of course, be overridden by additional
>   subclasses. An object must have an implementation for all of its
>   methods. You need to create a subclass that provides an implementation
>   for the abstract method.